# AsyncLocal holding a stack - seemingly solid code throws "Stack empty". Why?

Tags: c#, stack

I *know* that `AsyncLocal` is tricky. I'm not even 100% sure it's to blame, however. I can't understand how the below code is not "air-tight".

```cs
private readonly AsyncLocal<Stack<int>> _myStack = new AsyncLocal<Stack<int>>();

private void MyMethod()
{
    var myStack = _myStack.Value ?? (_myStack.Value = new Stack<int>());
    myStack.Push(42);
    try
    {
        // code here, which may recursively call the same function again.
        // all single-threaded without any async calls, though
    }
    finally
    {
        myStack.Pop(); // this occasionally throws "Stack empty"
    }
}
```

When the exception is thrown, the call stack is only "one deep" in this method.

There are no other references to `_myStack`, and `myStack` (the local var) is not passed down or used anywhere else.

Where does my understanding break down?  Regardless of the `AsyncLocal`, I grab a `Stack<>` object, push something to it - and no matter what happens, only pop once, in a `finally`.

There are no other exceptions thrown - the stack is not deep at all (1 or 2, maybe 3 levels in this case). There's no unmanaged code.

I do not have a minimal repro, and it seems to happen seemingly randomly. This is why `AsyncLocal` was introduced in the first place - in case two threads were getting involved and corrupting the internal state of the `Stack` perhaps.

Comment: If there is no async involved, have you tried with `ThreadLocal` instead of `AsyncLocal`? My suspicion is that AsyncLocal isn't much of a help, here. _"Because the task-based asynchronous programming model tends to abstract the use of threads, AsyncLocal<T> instances can be used to **persist data across threads**. "_ from [AsyncLocal<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.8), emphasis by me

Comment: You say that MyMethod() is not called recursively by async code, but is it ever called by multiple threads at the outer call level?

Comment: Oh, wait. I missed _"all single-threaded"_ - is it really? If so, then only the left out code remains as source of the error, I think.

Comment: The code that creates the stack object is not thread-safe I think. May be worth wrapping that in a lock to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: It looks to me like it should be using `Lazy<Stack<int>>` rather than plain `Stack<int>>`, since it is doing some lazy assignment.

Comment: It appears you're experiencing the copy-on-write behavior of data stored in the logical call context, described by Stephen Cleary in [his blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). It looks like `AsyncLocal<>.Value` doesn't get propagated back to the caller, and you end up with multiple copies of the `Stack`. Wrapping it with `Lazy` should indeed solve the problem.

Comment: @noseratio, but the stack reference is stored in a local variable that has nothing to do with `AsyncLocal<T>`, and there is clearly a push onto the stack this local references. I'm very curious what the real answer will be.

Comment: Could you maybe provide an excerpt of the generated IL code for that piece?

Comment: I think you will need to examine the body of the `try`-block, since I am unable to replicate the error [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BFKhOw). I suspect that you have an unequal number of push and pop calls in the `try`-block.